# Create a done button for UIPickerView

Tags: xcode, swift, uipickerview, toolbar, uitoolbar

I am currently trying to create a done button for a UIPickerView.

I believe that I have added in the code for a done button to show up but a done button does not show up in the simulator.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var genderTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var getGender: UIPickerView!

    @IBOutlet weak var preferenceTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var getPreference: UIPickerView!

    let gender = ["", "Male", "Female"]
    let preference = ["", "Male", "Female", "Both"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var theWidth = view.frame.size.width
        var elWidth = theWidth - 50

        // Adds title text field to the top
        var titleLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
        titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(25, 40, elWidth, 40)
        titleLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: (203.0/255.0), blue: (38.0/255.0), alpha: 1.0)
        titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Apple SD Gothic Neo", size: 28.0)
        titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        titleLabel.text = "Set up your profile"
        self.view.addSubview(titleLabel)

        getGender.hidden = true;
        genderTextField.placeholder = "Gender"
        genderTextField.delegate = self
        getGender.delegate = self
        getGender.frame = CGRectMake(0,view.frame.size.height-216, view.frame.size.width, 216)
        getPreference.hidden = true;
        preferenceTextField.placeholder = "Gender preference"
        preferenceTextField.delegate = self
        getPreference.delegate = self
        getPreference.frame = CGRectMake(0,view.frame.size.height-216, view.frame.size.width, 216)

        var toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
        toolBar.translucent = true
        toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 76/255, green: 217/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)
        toolBar.sizeToFit()

        var doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "donePicker")
        var spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        var cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "canclePicker")

        toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
        toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true

        genderTextField.inputView = getGender
        genderTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

        preferenceTextField.inputView = getPreference
        preferenceTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar


    }


    @IBAction func genderTextClick(sender: UITextField) {

        getGender.showsSelectionIndicator = true

        // Create toolbar
        var toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
        toolBar.translucent = true
        toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 76/255, green: 217/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)
        toolBar.sizeToFit()

        // Create buttons
        var doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "doneGenderPicker")
        var spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        var cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "cancelGenderPicker")

        // Assign buttons to toolbar
        toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
        toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true

        // Add pickerview and toolbar to textfield
        genderTextField.inputView = getGender
        genderTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

        sender.inputView = getGender

    }


    @IBAction func preferenceTextClick(sender: UITextField) {



        getPreference.showsSelectionIndicator = true

        // Create toolbar
        var toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
        toolBar.translucent = true
        toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 76/255, green: 217/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)
        toolBar.sizeToFit()

        // Create buttons
        var doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "donePreferencePicker")
        var spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        var cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "cancelPreferencePicker")

        // Assign buttons to toolbar
        toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
        toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true

        // Add pickerview and toolbar to textfield
        preferenceTextField.inputView = getPreference
        preferenceTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

        sender.inputView = getPreference

    }


    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        getGender.tag = 0
        getPreference.tag = 1

        if pickerView.tag == 0 {
            return gender.count
        } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            return preference.count
        }
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {

        getGender.tag = 0
        getPreference.tag = 1

        if pickerView.tag == 0 {
            return gender[row]
        } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            return preference[row]
        }
        return ""
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)  {

        getGender.tag = 0
        getPreference.tag = 1

        if pickerView.tag == 0 {
            genderTextField.text = gender[row]
//            getGender.hidden = true
        } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            preferenceTextField.text = preference[row]
//            getPreference.hidden = true
        }
    }

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if (textField == self.genderTextField) {
            getGender.hidden = false
        } else if (textField == self.preferenceTextField) {
            getPreference.hidden = false
        }
        return false
    }

    func doneGenderPicker() {
        genderTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    func cancelGenderPicker() {
        genderTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func donePreferencePicker() {
        preferenceTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    func cancelPreferencePicker() {
        preferenceTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }


//    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
//        
//        getGender.hidden = true
//        getPreference.hidden = true
//    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

so much!

[image: Picture of UIPicker(no toolbar shows up)]

Comment: remove the line with 'Thank you'. Rather upvote and accept the answers that help

Comment: What happens when you remove the spaceButton, does the doneButton show up right next to the cancelButton?  Or if you change it to `toolBar.setItems([doneButton, spaceButton, cancelButton], animated: false)` does the cancelButton disappear?

Comment: @dstudeba None of the buttons appear at all, let me show you a screenshot of the uipicker.

Comment: @Aditya i changed the thank you as well if you want to see

Answer (score 0):

Assign toolbar to textfield in textFieldShouldBeginEditing rather than on the IBAction. preferenceTextClick(_: UITextField) probably gets called later than that and hence, doesn't load the toolbar.